# How do I export Outlook 2013 mails and contacts to Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, contacts

I would like to export all of my emails and all of my contacts from Outlook 2013 to Thunderbird on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I do not want to install Thunderbird on Windows to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a program available on the Ubuntu Software Center called readpst - this command line program can convert pst files from outlook (you e-mails) to a format that Thunderbird can read in.  It's been quite a while since I did this, so I don't recall if this also handled the contacts.

```
readpst -u -o ~/dirname foo.pst
```

Contacts:

Contacts may be more difficult to pull over, as there is no real easy way to export contacts.  I'll put this example together using outlook2013, which is the obnly version I currently have running.  You know that you can send an outlook contact as a vcard, and what you want to do is send all outlook contacts as a vcard - unfortunately outlook will not send multiple contacts in a single file.

So...  Open your contacts in Outlook, select them all, and choose to forward them as business cards (vfc files).  Send the mail to yourself.  This is a pain, I know.  When you get the mail, choose to save all attachments in a single folder somewhere.  You will now have a folder full of vcf files.

Open a cmd (dos) window, change to the directory with all the contacts, and enter the command

```
copy *.vfc contacts.vcf
```

This will create a single file called contacts.vcf, with all of your contacts in it.  Copy this file to your Ubuntu system, perhaps on a thumb drive?

Alternatively you could perform this function on Ubuntu:  Create a directory in your home area, copy all of the vcf files from the e-mail into the home directory, open a terminal and navigate to this directory. The command would then be

```
cat *vcf >> ~/contacts.vcf
```

This will create a 'contacts.vcf' file in your home directory, with all of the individual contact files placed into it.

Open Thunderbird, click on Address Book, and choose 'Tools->Import' from the menus.  Tell thunderbird you would like to import an address book, and use the vcf file import, locate your contacts.vcf file and away you go.

Comment: Thanks will try READPST, but I think this command only handles the .pst file.

Comment: Very true - so in Outlook, create a pst file, and in the pst file create a directory for contacts, and copy your contacts there.  Additional subdirectories can be made for whats in your inbox...  I updated the answer slightly to include the form of the command that I used.

Comment: Hi I used the readpst command as suggested and ALL went well, I now have all the emails. I now need to try out the second suggestion for the import of all the contacts. Thanks so far.

Comment: Glad to hear it went well.

Comment: I have now tried all I know to copy the contacts to the newly created pst file and it just cannot get it to work. I know this is windows But without this step I cannot carry on. I created the pst file ( that worked ok) copied all the contacts to that file and then. Copied the file over to Thunderbird and used the same tool to import the emails and now nothing happens. I am sure I am missing a step somewhere. Help.

Comment: @JohnFerri  Updated answer (in a few minutes)

Comment: Charles, you are a STAR, it all worked perfectly. Thank you I can now concentrate on Ubuntu.

Comment: @JohnFerri  Glad to hear it worked well for you.  I made the switch completely about 4 months ago, and have only small reasons to run Windows in VM's now.  Please mark the answer as accepted, if everything went well!